# Angular Material Table with no data when adding sort and pagination

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material

I'm learning to use this great angular material component that is the data table. I managed to make it work with in my kind of customized app, but when I tried to add sort and pagination, the data went off despite being monitored in the logs.

I'm doing something wrong, can someone point me out in the right direction? The relevant code:

The base component that handles and receives all data:

```
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  public tableData: any;
  readonly displayedColumns = ['id', 'sol', 'earth_date', 'img_source'];
  readonly cameras: string[] = [
    'FHAZ',
    'RHAZ',
    'MAST',
    'NAVCAM',
    'CHEMCAM',
    'MAHLI',
    'MARDI',
    'PANCAM',
    'MINITES',
  ];
  readonly camera = 'FHAZ';
  roverData: Rover[];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.tableData);
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  eventCaptured($event) {
    this.dataService.searchByCamera($event).subscribe((data) => {
      this.roverData = this.tableData = data;
      console.log(this.tableData);
    });
  }
```

Passing data via Input (base component html):

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
      <app-content
      [roverData]="roverData"
      [dataSource]="dataSource"
      [displayedColumns]="displayedColumns"
      ></app-content>
    </div>
```

the content component which displays the table (TS)

```
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
 @Input() roverData: Rover[];
 @Input() dataSource: any;
 @Input() displayedColumns: string[];
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
 @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    console.log(changes);
  }
}
```

Content HTML (the table)

```
<mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let r"> {{r.id}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="sol">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sol </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let r"> {{r.sol}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="earth_date">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Earth Date </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let r"> {{r.earth_date}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="img_source">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Rover Image </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let r">
      
          <img  class="img-fluid" src="{{r.img_src}}" alt="rover camera">

    </div>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

The onChnges Hook displays the correct data, but its not being rendered. Why?

Comment: worked like a cham :) @yurzui, if you want to post an answer, points are yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you incorrectly updated `dataSource` for mat-table.

Since you're using `MatTableDataSource` then you need to go with:

```
this.dataSource.data = data;
```

but you updated original array `this.tableData = data;`